# Public transport to downtown Negombo

Tags: public-transport, sri-lanka, negombo

Are there any public transport available from Lewis Place ( beach side neighborhood) to down town Negombo ? Where to find it, and how long does it take ?

Answer (score 5):

It is only 2-3 km from the Lewis Place hotels to the Dutch Fort, so walking along the beach or down Sea Street is entirely feasible, although I have only done so during the day.

At any time of day or night, tuk-tuks are also readily available in the area, given the large number of tourists, and should cost around 200 LKR.

Bus 905 will connect you from Lewis Place all the way to the clock tower via the Negombo bus terminal and the railway station for 10 LKR, but do not expect a regular schedule.

From the northern reaches of Ethukala, you can also walk to the Kattuwa railway station for a quick 5-minute ride to Negombo Station. This does keep a regular schedule, but it is a limited one, and as with all local trains is quite crowded.